# How to call functions using variables as names from other files

Tags: python

Python won't let me call a function from another file in the same directory if I use variable names.

I've tried exec()

```
def Index():
    Functions = ["","Decimal_Into_Hex"]
    for x in range(1,len(Functions)):
        print(x,Functions[x])
    try:
        Function_To_Call = int(input("Which task would you like to call: "))
    except:
        print("Please enter a number")
        Index()
    else:
        FileName = Functions[Function_To_Call]
        Function = Functions[Function_To_Call]+"()"
        try:
            import FileName as Imp
        except:
            print("Not a file")
            Index()
        else:
            Imp.Function

Index()
```

It is supposed to get the function Decimal_Into_Hex from the file also named Decimal_Into_Hex, the purpose would be to be able to call functions from one single organized space however it just comes up with errors. I've gotten it working by putting the actual file name and function name however I wanted to make it solely call from the variables in the list.

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow. Questions seeking debugging help require a [mcve] to be on-topic. Note: "however it just comes up with errors. " Please provide the full error messages. Help us, help you.

Comment: But anyway, you are putting *strings* into your list of functions, they *happen* to correspond to *variable names*, but Python neither knows nor cares.  You need to put *the functions themselves in the list*.

Comment: Functions are first-class objects: `functions = [decimal_into_hex]; functions[0]()`.

Comment: Why not import all modules globally when starting, so that they don't have to be individually imported each time? (Hopefully there aren't _that_ many modules?)

Comment: Even if all modules were imported to call the functions with variable names still wouldn't work and lead back to the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help you get started, at a basic level.

```
import importlib                             # import a module to help you import so that you can import with your import             

filename = function = 'Decimal_To_Hex'

imp = importlib.import_module(filename)      # imports the module 'Decimal_To_Hex'
getattr(imp, function)()                     # calls Decimal_To_Hex.Decimal_To_Hex()
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is in this line:

> Function = Functions[Function_To_Call]+"()"

Take off the `+"()"` and just put `()`. That should call the function as a function, instead of the hybrid it's being called as now.

Comment: Im getting the error message:Function = Functions[Function_To_Call]()
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: This would work if *`Functions` actually contained functions*, but it doesn't.

Comment: Ah, you're right. Forgot that by the time I got down to the line I quoted. Alex, you might be better off making a dictionary and mapping each function to a name as a string. Then you can get the function from the string that it matches when you iterate through the list.

Comment: @Shocknoble or they can just add the functions to the list.

Comment: Right, they had said that they could get it to work by putting the functions themselves, but wanted to be able to get them as variables from the list.

Comment: How would I go about adding functions to a list when the functions do not exist until they are called in the line import FileName as Imp ?

Comment: Hm. You could make the list in the file you are importing them from. Or you could make the list and then append every function imported into the list upon import.

Comment: This index is designed to call from many different files so making the list after the import wouldn't work without importing everything. @Shocknoble

Comment: It kind of sounds like you'd be better off trying to build in a dll instead of a separate sort of 'home base' py file